# Add text annotation to seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create seaborn lmplot for a clustering result, data example are shown below:

```
    ID   CA     IP  clusters
    38  10.3    5.6   1
    59  10.4    6.1   0
    64  10.0    6.6   1
    35  10.6    5.6   1
    54  10.6    5.6   1
    60  10.2    8.2   1
```

There are two clusters (cluster 0 and cluster 1), and I want to **show the "ID" based on "ID" column on each scatter**. Tried the function of adding text as in [seaborn regplot](https://python-graph-gallery.com/46-add-text-annotation-on-scatterplot/) but there are errors saying "FacetGrid does not have text function".

Codes for seaborn plot:

```
ax = sns.lmplot('CA', 'IP', 
     data=df_tr, 
     fit_reg=False, 
     hue="clusters",  palette="Set1",
     scatter_kws={"marker": "D", "s": 50})

plt.title('Calcium vs Phosporus')
plt.xlabel('CA')
plt.ylabel('IP')
```

And the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) (used in the site you link to) return a matplotlib axes object which allows you to use the `text` function. However, `seaborn.lmplot` returns a FacetGrid.

Therefore you need to get the axes of the Facetgrid which you can do using

```
fgrid = sns.lmplot(...)
ax = fgrid.axes[0,0]  # fgrid.axes return an array of all axes in the figure, so we index the array
```

From here you can then use the function as shown in the link