# Add text to each point in a seaborn.relplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using below code below to generate a `relplot`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv")
df.head()
p1=sns.relplot(x="OS_Packages",y="Vulnerabilities",hue="OS_Distro",
               size="High_Vulnerabilities",sizes=(400,1000), data = df)
plt.show()
```

I need to add text to each points in the plot.  How I can do that? I have searched but only got results only for `regplot.` I am looking for adding text to the points of a `relplot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192085/add-text-annotation-to-seaborn-lmplot), you have to access the axes of the FacetGrid that is returned by the `relplot`.

A simple reproduction of your question with a point annotated:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'OS_Packages':[0,1,2,4], 'Vulnerabilities': [6,7,3,7], 
     'text':['point1','point2','point3','point4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

p1 = sns.relplot(x='OS_Packages', y='Vulnerabilities',data=df )
ax = p1.axes[0,0]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]
    text = row[2]
    ax.text(x+.05,y,text, horizontalalignment='left')
```

This will return the following:

[image]

Comment: @BhupinderKaur great!  Since you found the answer helpful, please select it as the accepted answer so that others will know it solved this question.

Comment: is it possible to assign colors to these points manually. For example, I want point1 to have dark blue. point 2 to have light blue, point 3 has green

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop by using `seaborn.objects`. Here is an example using the same data as in the answer from jtweeder:

```
import seaborn.objects as so
d = {'OS_Packages':[0,1,2,4], 'Vulnerabilities': [6,7,3,7], 
 'text':['point1','point2','point3','point4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
so.Plot(data=df,x='OS_Packages',y='Vulnerabilities',text='text').add(so.Dots()).add(so.Text(valign='top'))
```